# What are some of the fastest ways to process this?

Tags: python, django, performance, hadoop, amazon-ec2

I'm kind-of at a crossroads in my application - where I'm using python/django, mysql, and ubuntu 12.04

My application will be accessing other applications online, making indexes of their path structure, and submitting forms. If you think of this happening with 10s or 100s of accounts with 1 or more domain names each, the performance can get a little out of hand.

My initial thinking was to setup an ec2 environment to distribute the load of accessing all of these paths on each domain across many ec2 instances, each running celery/rabbitmq to distribute the processing load across these ec2 instances.

The thing is - I want to store the results of submitting forms in which I access. I read that I would likely need to use a nosql db (e.g. hadoop, redis, etc).

My question to you all is:

- Is there a different way to use celery/rabbitmq with a SQL-db and what are the advantages/disadvantages?
  I can see one problem with having to use nosql : the learning curve .
- Secondly: is there some other way to distribute the (processing) load of several python scripts being run at the same time on multiple ec2 environments?

Thank you.

Comment: Could certainly do this with multiple machines running celery. It will distribute the tasks out to the slave nodes. As for nosql, I'd look into redis and mongodb. Both are good at what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a different way to use celery/rabbitmq with a SQL-db and what
>   are the advantages/disadvantages? I can see one problem with having to
>   use nosql : the learning curve

Yes.

1. If you are talking about storing your Django application/model data, you can use it with any SQL type of database as long as you have the Python bindings for it. Most popular SQL databases have python binding.
2. If you are referring to storing task results in a specific backend there's support for multiple databases/protocols SQL and noSQL. I believe there's no specific advantage or disadvantage between storing the results either in SQL (MySQL, Posgtgres) or noSQL (Mongo, CouchDB), but that's just my personal opinion and that depends on what type of application you are running. These are some of the examples that you can use for SQL databases (from their docs):

   ```
   # sqlite (filename) CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = ‘db+sqlite:///results.sqlite’
   # mysql CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = ‘db+mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo’
   # postgresql CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = ‘db+postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/mydatabase’
   # oracle CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = ‘db+oracle://scott:tiger@127.0.0.1:1521/sidname’
   ```
3. If you are referring to a broker (queuing mechanism), celery only supports RabbitMQ and redis.

> Secondly: is there some other way to distribute the (processing) load
>   of several python scripts being run at the same time on multiple ec2
>   environments?

That's exactly what celery does, you can setup your workers on multiple machines which can be different EC2 instances.  Then all you have to do is point their celery installations to the same queues/broker in your configs.  If you want redundancy in your broker (RabbitMQ and/or Redis) you should look at setting them up in clustered configs.

Comment: Excellent thoroughness. Thank you @Rico

Comment: In your #3 response though: will it store the values on a nosql db like redis if distributed? Or is it possible to use mysql (on each ec2 node) ?

Comment: @CodeTalk sure but that's the queuing mechanism not the task results